# How can I outline a path in Inkscape to make an object?

Tags: inkscape, path

I was able to successfully outline an oval by using Path-Inset and Path-Outset. I then aligned the two inset and outset objects, and used Path-Exclusion to create the object that I could add/change an stroke color and fill color. But, that oval was closed path.

I would like to be able to draw a thick (15px or bigger) curvy path, change it to an object with a stroke color and fill color.

I would also like to draw an "X" with two open paths, combine them and outline it/change it into an object that could have a stroke color and fill color. Just using Path-Outset did not work. But, I didn't really expect that to work since it wasn't a single closed path.

I was thinking of having to take a screenshot and use the AutoTrace. But, there has to be a better way to do it than that.

With an "X" drawn with two straight lines, I could zoom in and click with the Pen Tool to create the outline/object. But, that would be difficult if the crossed lines were curvy.

This idea/process could also be used to create custom arrows with a V-shaped path and a stem path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+C

Stroke to Path.

Will do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you very much, jqning. I was able to use the Path - Union after using Stroke to Path to get an X-shaped object with fill and stroke options. This is exactly what I needed